# Connect to SQL Server for PHP: Connection could not be established

Tags: php, sql-server, wampserver

> **Connection could not be established.** Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 10061 [code] => 10061 [2] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection
>   could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]TCP Provider:
>   No connection could be made because the target machine actively
>   refused it. ) [1] => Array ( [0] => HYT00 [SQLSTATE]
>           => HYT00 [1] => 0 [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC
>   Driver 11 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired ) [2] => Array ( [0] =>
>   08001 [SQLSTATE] => 08001 [1] => 10061 [code] => 10061 [2] =>
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A network-related or
>   instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection
>   to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if
>   instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow
>   remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online.
>   [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]A
>   network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not
>   accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
>   configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL
>   Server Books Online. ) )

Code:

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost\sqlexpress, 1433"; //serverName\instanceName, portNumber (default is 1433)
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"QLBH", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"123456");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

if($conn) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
}
else{
    echo "<b>Connection could not be established.</b><br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Are remote connections enabled on the MSSQL server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $serverName = "(local)";

$connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"dbname" Username=>Username,PWD=password);



/* Connect using Windows Authentication. */

$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionOptions);

if( $conn === false )

      { die( FormatErrors( sqlsrv_errors() ) ); }
```

connectionOptions give all conncetion data in array.
sql_connect contains only two parameters.